# Python - finding the last element of a list

Tags: python

I'm going through some of the exercises on codingbat.com.  The exercise I'm stuck on is this:

"Given an array of ints, return True if 6 appears as either the first or last element in the array. The array will be length 1 or more.

```
first_last6([1, 2, 6]) → True

first_last6([6, 1, 2, 3]) → True

first_last6([13, 6, 1, 2, 3]) → False"
```

Here is what I put for my answer.  I know it's incorrect, but I'm not sure what I did wrong.

```
def first_last6(nums):
    if nums[0] == 6 or nums[len(nums)-1] == 6:
       return True
    else:
       return False
```

Comment: How do you know it's incorrect?  Did it give the wrong answer?  Did it fail with a `SyntaxError`?  Did your computer explode?

Comment: `if nums[0] == 6 or nums[len(nums)-1] == 6:return True`  ... this construct is just `if True:return True` why not just return the boolean result?

Comment: Actually i don't know if it is wrong.  It makes sense to me, but when i submit that code on codingbat.com it says it is incorrect.  I should give myself more credit!

Answer (score 5):

Your solution will actually work.  Here is a slightly better one though:

```
def first_last6(nums):
    return nums[0] == 6 or nums[-1] == 6
```

Answer (score 3):

`nums[-1]` gives you the last element

Answer (score 1):

Update:
      After reading below comments, `6 == llist[0] or 6 == llist[-1]` will work more efficiently   than creating a tuple.

Just do `6 in (llist[0],llist[-1])`, you dont need to write a function for that.

Comment: this is the answer I would be looking for as an interviewer

Comment: why generate a tuple and use membership testing instead of a simple `or` clause?

Comment: @D.Shawley Agreed. :)

Comment: @JoranBeasley: why would you want to create a tuple in memory? `L[0]==6 or L[-1]==6` works. If you're looking for scalability, `any(L[i]==6 for i in (0,-1))` would work better, as the created tuple contains `int`s and not any objects that the list contains, which may require more memory

Comment: I like your `any` answer ... i dunno `in` is just a great python operator imho

Answer (score 1):

for find last index in python you can use -1 as index of list.

you just need to change nums[-1] instead of nums[len(nums)-1]

def first_last6(nums):

```
if nums[0] == 6 or nums[-1] == 6:
   return True

else:
   return False
```

Answer (score 0):

```
L[0]==6 or L[-1]==6
```

`L[0]` checks the element at the `0`-th index, i.e. the first element
`L[-1]` checks the element at the `-1`-th index, i.e. the last element. Note that this is equivalent to checking `L[len(L)-1]`

If you want to make it nice and scalable, you might consider doing this:

```
CHECK_INDICES = (0,-1)
any(L[i]==6 for i in CHECK_INDICES)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python3 you can also get the first and last like this. A `ValueError` is thrown if there is only a single item in nums

```
def first_last6(nums):
    first, *middle, last = nums
    return first == 6 or last == 6
```